# Empty error popup TextView

Tags: android

i `setError` in TextView

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.change_password_new_password))
        .setError("error");
```

but i get just error icon and error popup with no text when i press that icon

[image]

it looks like the forgotten clarify what he wants to get,
i want to make text in popup visible

Comment: what happens if you click on the icon?

Comment: Please paste your whole code

Comment: @Blackbelt as i wrote empty error popup show, i add img

Comment: @kirtiavaiya what exactly do you want to get, theres is about 300lines for that form, and this is only place where i set error for TextView

Comment: it is probably because the text is white by default. Have you tried changing it with a spannable or html ?

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks that lead me to solution :) i used <span style="... but i had to replace that with <font... like i posted in answer

Comment: good for you, enjoy it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

i set `Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>this is the error</font>")` as error and now i can see text :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: it is answer for my problem, im author of question and author of this solution

Answer (score 0):

for your case,I think you need something:

```
TextView password= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.change_password_new_password);
password.setError("error", getResources() .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```